# $_POST is not working in custom urls

Tags: php, yii

I have used custom urls in my application. When i create message it redirect me to the create form but when i submit the form it redirects back to the same form again. There is a condition in the controller if the $_POST variable is set then save it else redirect to the form. I thought the $_POST variable is not setting but when i print it in the form it was printed there. So, if the $_POST variable is set then why the condition fails? Following is my custom urls. Before using custom urls it was working ok.

```
  'urlManager' => array(
                'urlFormat' => 'path',
                'showScriptName' => false,
                'rules' => array(
                    '' => 'questions/index',
                    'messages' => 'messages/index',
                    'tags' => 'tags/index',
                    'login' => 'site/login',
                    'signup' => 'users/create',
                    '<id:\w+>' => 'users/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    'gii' => 'gii',
                    'gii/<controller:\w+>' => 'gii/<controller>',
                    'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'gii/<controller>/<action>',
                ),
            ),
```

And this is my .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Is there something wrong here..?

**EDIT**

Here is my controller code.

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id);

        if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
            $model->attributes = $_POST['User'];
            if ($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
        }

        $this->render('update_info', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Where is your controller code?

Comment: Custom urls should not affect this bahavior, perhaps you changed some code elsewhere. Could you post your controller action code?

Comment: So, is data saving to the db once you submit? Generally, it may be an issue with your redirect call on the controller, but that is not posted. I can't see  problem with your config file or .htaccess file

Comment: Oh my mistake. I was looking for the issue for two hours. In my model there were some fields in required section and i didn't show them in the form. So, i removed them from the model and its good to go. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect isn't happening then `$model->save()` isn't completing successfully. You can use `print_r($model->getErrors());` to see the validation errors.